# Nickel-Titanium shape memory effect

Tags: material-science

Nitinol is a shape memory alloy that changes shape with temperature. I read a research paper claiming you could use it as a wire that expands inside the body (37C) and can contract upon cooling (1). However, other articles suggest it recovers its original, undeformed shape upon heating above its "transformation temperature", not through cooling. So how do i make sense of these contradictory concepts?

(1) http://www.intechopen.com/books/biomedical-engineering-from-theory-to-applications/orthopaedic-modular-implants-based-on-shape-memory-alloys